# form data upload multiple files through ajax together with foreach

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax, codeigniter

I have a form with multiple fields in it. Also, the form is being submitted through form data method using ajax to a php file.

The following is the javascript code submitting the form data.I am uploading multiple files in each input file and need to send the id on submit with file array...Each time i am uploading the file and when clicked on submit i am getting the last iteration referral_id of foreach loop....PLease can some one help me out where i have gone wrong....

```
<form method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="uploadforms" onsubmit="return submitForm();">
<?php 
  foreach($result as $value)
 {?>
<div class="form-group">
    <h2>Choose Files</h2>
    <h3><?php echo $value->test_name;?></h3>
    <input type="file" name="files[]" class="form-control filein" id="files" multiple />
    <input type="text" name="referral_id" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $value->ID;?>" />
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <input type="submit" name="fileSubmit" value="UPLOAD" data-referralid="<?php echo $value->ID;?>" id="submitbtn"/>
</div>
<?php 

}
?>
</form>
```

i want to post referral_id which is passed in submit input....i am not getting error....the data are being submitted but when i upload the first iteration submit button and submit the form i am getting the last iteration referral_id. Suppose the rray for referral_id is $referral_id = array(1, 2, 3, 4); Each time when i submit i am getting 4 as output

```
$("form").submit(function(evt){   
evt.preventDefault();
var referral_id=$("#submitbtn").data('referralid');
alert(referral_id);
var formData = new FormData($('#uploadforms')[0]);
console.log(formData);
$.ajax({
url: '<?php echo base_url("Upload_Files1"); ?>',
type: 'POST',
data: {referral_id: referral_id, files: formData},
async: false,
cache: false,
contentType: false,
enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
processData: false,
success: function (response) {
alert(response);
}
});
return false;
});
```

Comment: what error you are getting?

Comment: i am not getting error....the data are being submitted but when i upload the first iteration submit button and submit the form i am getting the last iteration referral_id. Suppose the rray for referral_id is $referral_id = array(1, 2, 3, 4); Each time when i submit i am getting 4 as output

Comment: why don't you directy append the referral_id in the FormData like formData.append('referral_id ', 'value').

Comment: i tried that methos but i was getting the same value

Comment: Thanks @RopAli Munshi ...i got the output ...Please find below.... The form id as well as referral_id input should be dynamic

Answer (score 0):

I got the output

```
<form method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="uploadforms" onsubmit="return submitForm();">
<?php 
  foreach($result as $value)
 {?>
<div class="form-group">
    <h2>Choose Files</h2>
    <h3><?php echo $value->test_name;?></h3>
    <input type="file" name="files[]" class="form-control filein" id="files" multiple />
    <input type="text" name="referral_id" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $value->ID;?>" />
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <input type="submit" name="fileSubmit" value="UPLOAD" data-referralid="<?php echo $value->ID;?>" id="submitbtn"/>
</div>
<?php 

}
?>
</form>
```

Ajax script

```
$("form").submit(function(evt){   
evt.preventDefault();
var referral_id=$("#submitbtn").data('referralid');
alert(referral_id);
var formData = new FormData($('#uploadforms')[0]);
console.log(formData);
$.ajax({
url: '<?php echo base_url("Upload_Files1"); ?>',
type: 'POST',
data: {referral_id: referral_id, files: formData},
async: false,
cache: false,
contentType: false,
enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
processData: false,
success: function (response) {
alert(response);
}
});
return false;
});
```